# Javascript событие для всех ссылок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как заменить jquery код на javascript?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (event) {

  event.preventDefault();

});
```

Суть в том, что нужно повесить событие на все ссылки, не используя jQuery. Ссылки могут появляться новые после ajax. Они тоже должны обрабатывать событие.

Я пробовал:

```
 document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    var link = event.target.closest('a');

    if (!link) return;

    event.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

Но closest плохо поддерживается браузерами без полифилов =(
Так же пробовал через event.path найти дочерний элемент A, но e.path не работает в сафари...

Может подскажете какой то способо реализовать эту идею именно через document.addEventListener, без доп функций и тд.

(closest и event.path нужны были для того, чтобы избежать нерабочих картинок в ссылка и тд, так как event.target будет img, а не A)

Comment: «Но closest плохо поддерживается браузерами без полифилов» — почему бы не поставить полифилл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    let current = e.target;
    while(current != document.body){
        if(current.tagName == 'A'){
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
        }
        else current = current.parentNode;
    }
});
```

Comment: Вот такая ссылка работать не будет: `<a href=example.com><b>Жирная ссылка!</b></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Добавляешь каждой ссылке `class="needToClick"`
После чего

```
var arr = []; 
arr = document.getElementsbyclassname('needToClick');
```

Затем через forEach() просто навешиваешь события которые тебе необходимы.